# Change crop focus for specific styles on certain existing images

Tags: 7, media

I just migrated a 15,000 story news website and am doing some quality testing on that migration.

The site uses about 5 image styles for various things, including a REALLY wide one (~960x400px) at the top of every story. This works awesome for images with horizontal/landscape orientation, but causes some weird cropping for images with vertical/portrait orientation.

I don't want to use a solution like [imagefield_crop](http://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_crop), which will change the cropping on all images (square thumbs are less problematic, for instance). Any idea of modules that allow me to override the default cropping focus from Image Styles for specific styles on specific images?

Thanks!

(Additionally, these images are in [Field Collections](http://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection), so any module suggested should work with that. Currently, it seems that [imagecrop](http://www.drupal.org/project/imagecrop) does not.)

Comment: Also just tried [Manual Crop](http://www.drupal.org/projects/manual_crop) and it doesn't seem to work on images smaller than what I've set the crop size to), which some of the older images are.

Comment: Actually, removing the size constraints on Manual Crop makes it work a lot better. Also seems to work with Field Collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my purposes, [Manual Crop](http://www.drupal.org/project/manual_crop) was the best solution.